# iOS TextField (other widgets) appears to have a "overflow hidden" in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image: iOS simulator]

I'm an android developer and recently just tried working on Xcode. I'm running into a problem where UI widgets are longer than expected in simulator but are OK in storyboard. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set auto layout constraints to resize the text field automatically because on the storyboard it is wider and the width of the simulator is smaller but because you seem to not have set the auto layout constraints, it does not know how to resize.

[Auto Layout constraints Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

Use auto layout .
1) Click on text field

2) Click on the pyramid shaped icon in the bottom left and click on reset to suggested constraints.

Learn about auto layouts

Answer (score 0):

the one thing to remember is the storyboard is not necessarily the screen size.  on your text field you would want to set up at least the constraints to the left and right.  Possible the top as well if you want it to remain that distance from the top of the screen when you rotate to landscape mode